# Why does Bootstrap div.navbar show in Safari but not Firefox or Chrome when working with the collapsednav?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I have a strange Bootstrap thing happening with me! I've tried all sorts but still nothing seems to fix this. navbar navbar-default seems to show in Safari just below bootstrap's nav toggle, however doesn't show in Firefox or Chrome? I want do not want it shown, as it makes the top section look like it has huge bottom padding on it! Blegh.

[Here's a few images of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EfHd.jpg) and here is the actual [webpage](http://rosssimpson.co.uk/multistorage/width1) I'm working on.

It only seems to show out of place, when I've shrunken the browser size down, and when viewing on a mobile phone/tablet.

Thanks!

Comment: try inspect element and see if it has `display:none` or `visibility:none` or `opacity:none` for the affected element

Comment: @DanielCheung Nope, none of those above in the inspector, if there was those though, wouldn't that make it hidden in both browsers? It seems to show in one, but not the other? Thanks for your reply though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, .navbar had min-height: auto; but for some reason safari wasn't noticing this, however I just changed that to auto and it did what I need it to do! Sweet.